# Dual monitor wrong screen focus during drag-and-drop

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, gconf

I have a dual monitor set-up which is helpful when designing or programming. Usually I'll have both screens used with full size windows. My left monitor I guess would be the main monitor since it has the 3-D Unity Launcher.

I'd say 90 percent of the time I use the right monitor for workspace and the left monitor for tool-space or as a file/folder browser. If I try to grab the screen on the Left to drag it to the right, the screen on the right actually gets the "focus" and I end up dragging it around. This isn't a major issue, but it would be nice to have a fix. I've tried using Gconf-Settings to adjust the sensitivity, but haven't had much success. Any tips?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!